# TA-lib python, How use MAVP - Moving average with variable period

Tags: python, ta-lib

```
real = MAVP(close, periods, minperiod=2, maxperiod=30, matype=0)
```

i am trying to use this method but it raises an error because the periods parameters,
How to use this method for Dataframe like this [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This period parameter must be passed as an array of the periods you want to get. I got the Apple stock price from Yahoo Finance and got a moving average for the entire period I got it.

```
import yfinance as yf
data = yf.download("AAPL", start="2020-01-01", end="2021-01-01")

data.head()
    Open    High    Low     Close   Adj Close   Volume
Date                        
2020-01-02  74.059998   75.150002   73.797501   75.087502   74.333511   135480400
2020-01-03  74.287498   75.144997   74.125000   74.357498   73.610840   146322800
2020-01-06  73.447502   74.989998   73.187500   74.949997   74.197395   118387200
2020-01-07  74.959999   75.224998   74.370003   74.597504   73.848442   108872000
2020-01-08  74.290001   76.110001   74.290001   75.797501   75.036385   132079200

import talib as ta
import numpy as np

data.reset_index(drop=False,inplace=True)
periods = data.Date
real = ta.MAVP(data.Close, periods, minperiod=2, maxperiod=30, matype=0)

real
0             NaN
1             NaN
2             NaN
3             NaN
4             NaN
          ...    
248    131.465004
249    134.330002
250    135.779999
251    134.294998
252    133.205002
Length: 253, dtype: float64
```